# How to call drupal cron multipe times until done

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, cron

I'm working on a wamp development environment and testing how long it takes to get the site indexed. I'm doing this by running cron manually.

The problem is that if there's **700 jobs** in the `job_queue`, each run of cron does only some of them, so I need to run cron several times. How could I keep calling cron in a loop until there are no more jobs left in the `job_queue`?

Also, I'm open to any drush alternatives. I'm aware of drush cron, but this also does only some of the jobs each run, so needs to be run again manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run something all at once until it's done, cron is the wrong tool for the job; [batch API](http://drupal.org/node/180528) is the tool for that. Unfortunately the search module is written to update only on cron, but there's not a lot of code in [search_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/search_cron/6) to copy into a batch function. So I'd suggest going the batch route rather wrapping some sort of pseudo-batch around cron, as your end goal doesn't seem to involve cron at all.

Answer (score 3):

step 1. - Run cron every minute
step 2. - Just check if the script is already running. If so - close the "new script"

```
$lid='';
if(is_array($argv) && isset($argv[1])) {
    $lid=$argv[1];
}
if($lid!=='') {
  $xx=array();
  exec('ps x | grep "thefile.php '.$lid.'" | grep -v "grep"', &$xx);
  if(count($xx)>1) {
    die('Script '.$lid.' running already... exiting... '."\n");
  }
}
```

Put it in cron with every minute

```
php thefile.php 1
php thefile.php 2
php thefile.php 3
```

to run 3 scripts at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

`drush search-index` will generate the remaining search index for you.